Nest JS, enviar miles de datos a la base de datos
tengo un problema con mi función de NestJS,
Necesito enviar 300 mil registros a mi base de datos, no es un POST, es un PATCH,
la función para saber que datos actualizar lo tengo, pero a la hora de subir los datos encontré 2 problemas:
1.- Enviar todos los datos me devolvia un error, dice que son demasiados datos para enviar.
2.- Hacer un ciclo for y poner ahi mi query, lo intenté y se llevo literalmente días.
Hay alguna forma de hacerlo más eficiente?
Por lotes o algo parecido?
Gracias.
for (let i = 0; i < readFile.length; i++) {
        try {
          const aseguradoFile = readFile[i];
          const findAsegurado = usuarios.find(asegurado => {
            const removeGuion = usuarios.fc_nombre_usuario?.replace(/-/g, ' ');
            const removeDobleGuion = removeGuion?.replace(/--/g, ' ');
            const removeDobleEspacio = removeDobleGuion?.replace(/  /g, ' ');
            return removeDobleEspacio.toUpperCase().trim() == String(usuarioFile.Nombre_Completo).toUpperCase().trim();
          });
          usuariosFromFile.push(findUsuario);
/*           const jsonres = {
            ...aseguradoFile,
            ...findAsegurado,
            rfc: calcularRFC(usuarioFile.Nombre, usuarioFile.Paterno, usuarioFile.Materno, findUsuario.fecha_nacimiento)
          } */
          
          const toUpdate = {
            id_usuario: findUsiario.id_usuario,
            rfc: calcularRFC(usuarioFile.Nombre, usuarioFile.Paterno, usuarioFile.Materno, findUsuario.fecha_nacimiento),
            recalculado: rfc !== findUsuario.rfc ? 1 : 0,
            error: 0
          };
          nombres.push(toUpdate);
          //console.log("toUpdate", toUpdate);
          console.log("asegurado::", i);
        } catch (error) {
          console.log("Error al actualizar el registro", error);
          const toUpdate = {
id_usuario: findUsiario.id_usuario,
            rfc: null,
            recalculado: 0,
            error: 1
          };
          errors.push(toUpdate);
        };
      };
      const finalArray = [...nombres, ...errors];
      const toUpdate = {
       //id_usuario: () => `CASE id_usuario ${finalArray.map(usuario => `WHEN ${usuario.id_usuario} THEN ${asegurado.id_usuario}`).join(' ')} END`,
      };
      await this.checkNombreExcelRepository
        .createQueryBuilder()
        .update(CheckNombreExcel)
        .set(toUpdate)
        .where('id_usuario IN (:...ids)', { ids: usuarioFromFile.map(usuario => usuario.id_usuario) })
        .execute();
      return {
        total: usuariosFromFile.length,
        message: 'Datos actualizados correctamente',
        code : HttpStatus.OK
      };
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error al actualizar los datos', error);
      throw new HttpException('Error al actualizar los datos', HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    };

Gracias por su ayuda

Parece que tienes un caso raro aquí, ¿este caso de uso se va a usar varias veces?
Lo comento porque si es solamente una vez tal vez lo mejor sea crear un script o un seeder para modificar la base de datos directamente.
